# Question about nodejs using 'async-lock' return value

Tags: node.js, typescript, concurrency

I used **async-lock** module for my **typescript** program of **concurrency**.
As I use this, I want to return the result in `lock.acquire(...) {...}`, but it's not working well.
How can I return the value? I'll be grateful for any advice about this. Thanks!

```
public async getValue(key: string): Promise<any> {
    const base = this;
    lock.acquire(key, async function (done) {
        base.logger.info(`${key} lock enter`);
        if (!await base.myRepository.checkDBTable(key)) {
            const valueFromNetwork: number = await base.getValueFromNetwork(key);
            const initResult: MyEntity = await base.myRepository.initNonce(key, valueFromNetwork);
            if (!initResult) {
                throw new Error('initValue failed...');
            }
            base.logger.debug(JSON.stringify(initResult, null, 4));
        }
        const valueFromDB: number = await base.myRepository.getValueFromDB(key);
        if (valueFromDB === -1 || valueFromDB === undefined) {
            throw new Error('getValueFromDB failed...');
        } else {
            const updateResult: MyEntity = await base.myRepository.updateValue(key, valueFromDB);
            if (!updateResult) {
                throw new Error('updateValue failed...');
            }
            base.logger.info(`${valueFromDB}`);
            base.logger.info(`${key} lock done`);
            done();
        }

// I'd like to return valueFromDB above.

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can implement a wrapper around `lock.aquire` (Recommended as it is a little easier to read and can handle acquisition errors):

```
public async getValue(key: string): Promise<any> {
  const base = this;
  const done = await this.aquireLock(key);
  base.logger.info(`${key} lock enter`);
  if (!await base.myRepository.checkDBTable(key)) {
    const valueFromNetwork: number = await base.getValueFromNetwork(key);
    const initResult: MyEntity = await base.myRepository.initNonce(key, valueFromNetwork);
    if (!initResult) {
      throw new Error('initValue failed...');
    }
    base.logger.debug(JSON.stringify(initResult, null, 4));
  }
  const valueFromDB: number = await base.myRepository.getValueFromDB(key);
  if (valueFromDB === -1 || valueFromDB === undefined) {
    throw new Error('getValueFromDB failed...');
  } else {
    const updateResult: MyEntity = await base.myRepository.updateValue(key, valueFromDB);
    if (!updateResult) {
      throw new Error('updateValue failed...');
    }
    base.logger.info(`${valueFromDB}`);
    base.logger.info(`${key} lock done`);
    done();
  }
  return valueFromDB;
}
private async aquireLock(key: string): Promise<() => void> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    lock.acquire(key, done => {
      resolve(done);
    }, (err)=>{ // in case our aquire fails(times out, etc.)
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQQM4E8B2BjAMhDBrOAMyghDgCIBDVTAWgBtc9yBuAWAChOMI0l5G+OAF44aAKYB3RDWxMAFAEp2XDjBRhxcALIoAomhjB1IuJTQoV3etSRwMcAN6c4cRgHN34qAC4zFlVcQFAAlcUgkY2gUP3NLFzgvGAA1SnoAV3EAMRIQADlxGEloPFiAhLB0gCN6YAdqdAck1IzxeTxxGLh+KGA0d0U-AAVc4CRxAB44gD4nBNcePngq6i1RGAALMcDXe15+OAATXjWzSUpjOE2xgDpKAEd04ChxHHx2zuV5uBXxm48vFAbn1CBB5AADAAkjg6KAAvm4mHBxIZvOCvhxdnBgIQ4PIAISUc6XX7iG7BMIRKJQFA3DAbcT4AAiACEACqUGptWGKRRzTFYvZLOAANzSmRypAKRRKfjQ6RAVW8piJF2WqxuzXF2Vy0uKUDwHxQGMFQoOfWMYSQ6XoMD8ugMRhMolVJI1FPCEEiMGiwLQxjyvAw3M6ABpRdrJflCvq8CbBTi8fiLTArTaYHznALTZsSNIJNI9FASFB5AByFMtTJEC70cSHG6NsvxrFw76uUn-CCebw3Q7iKrpdzyABSAGUAPJ5G49PruHEoeQptO28Py+j0cMAFl5O1cbezZvgYtaUdZcoVSqgKuJ6r+HqpPppmsKVZ1pFZRpb2Nx8hPEtyVkRGEURaAARjgAAfSCI1PQCWWA0R0jQftCD6etM3bK4NjzMQpDgIsS3LLU4I-BDCFretGxuZs9zgBFxHocZ+VNRYDnSMBDkoGBxBXO0dH0QxjBQG81R+d1Qk9b1fQ4rieLfI1w3-d8QFZb9XETAlZO43jxGtW1MMPLFcwgfN8MI6By20+TtRrYA6wbJt1PorDOwBXsQTBKFHGUs8WThdE6I7DV3KBTyIWhWEEUEAhjgkQKsLitpvwPLEXhgdIoDQWCALInZUrgMBejFHizFkMxHmeV4FFhPxZ36QY4BGUgxkmJQRFmEUIGAQ5ZizNLCky7KCya0ZxnkeQXiQCB6BFcRwxeAArRkMw6ljBRiu4MEql5FKOE41v6004Cmma5vkJLnLhcN5G8KBFGEaZHDgAB6F7sWyjBVjgCBMoqp4Xjspj5CMEA9J+9IYHDQoMBuRQsI0whbuLRQjuOk7xGWjAYGR+6gt2ArW3hw84WJ-dODhIA)

2. Or, you can use a function constructor (even if it is an anti-pattern):

```
getValue(key: string): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const base = this;
    lock.acquire(key, async function (done) {
      base.logger.info(`${key} lock enter`);
      if (!await base.myRepository.checkDBTable(key)) {
        const valueFromNetwork: number = await base.getValueFromNetwork(key);
        const initResult: MyEntity = await base.myRepository.initNonce(key, valueFromNetwork);
        if (!initResult) {
          reject(new Error('initValue failed...'));
        }
        base.logger.debug(JSON.stringify(initResult, null, 4));
      }
      const valueFromDB: number = await base.myRepository.getValueFromDB(key);
      if (valueFromDB === -1 || valueFromDB === undefined) {
        reject(new Error('getValueFromDB failed...'));
      } else {
        const updateResult: MyEntity = await base.myRepository.updateValue(key, valueFromDB);
        if (!updateResult) {
          reject(new Error('updateValue failed...'));
        }
        base.logger.info(`${valueFromDB}`);
        base.logger.info(`${key} lock done`);
        done();
      }
      resolve(valueFromDB)
    });
  })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=4&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQQM4E8B2BjAMhDBrOAMyghDgCIBDVTAWgBtc9yBuAWAChOMI0l5G+OAF44aAKYB3RDWxMAFAEp2XDjBRhxcALIoAomhjB1IuJTQoV3etSRwMcAN6c4cRgHN34qAC4zFlVcQFAAlcUgkY2gUP3NLFzgvGAA1SnoAV3EAMRIQADlxGEloPFiAhKTUjPF5PHEYuH4oYDR3RT8ABVzgJHEAHjiAPicE1yhC9Kg0MSk4LtIemvlxpAh6ADdxABo4cYArcQwYRRFh5w5XS-tefjgAI2otURgACx7Aq7cmADpKDABHdLAca1eo7ajoByEdKYIy8ODyAAmvHEJ3On0uD163w8Xig3xahAg8gABgASRx1FAAXy+QnEhm8JOUo0+wEICIAhJRJJRjPdHt9gmEIlEoChvhgXoc8AARABCABVKHd6DUqYo0ayMTw+PB1mlMjlSAUiiU-Gh0iA7t5TDy+fAseJvpVDdlcqbilA8KCUCyLhjLrrbi1jGEkOl6DA-LoDEYTKJ7fynULQuEIJEYNECWhjHleBh1WC4Abqsb8oUvXh-YHLuyuaGYOHI8cRgHa2NxAcjvIJNI9FASFB5AByRtVTJEPlqxHfOcjzUfWvU7WfFO47zfRHiO7pdzyABSAGUAPJ5b5NFrudkoeSN5tRnaW+j0HYAFkXq9cK-bn2D+rdcsFQtK0bSgO1eWTQVhXTTNs1dMtcgVX0a0Det5FLI0kPlERhFEWgAEY4AAH2IktAOw3DRBhbdCBacRES1X8MX2Q4YF7WYByHUcEKw0gFSnYAZznb4F1QjFaXEehejbDtrj1OB0jARFKBgcQH2jHR9EMYwUAgh0BWxGDRSzcVviUlS1InIsUB2TD3X4+VxLQjl5E5CzVPU8QIyjJi5M7bt2L7OAuOgUcPKst1BOE+dP2Yz4fzk9cIE8TdCWJclHHsoD5WpZkl0DZLUvxdLSQpKlaUEAhkQkfKv0uGqamcq5EsDFY1k2DCKMcxRV2pZz+oSH9qSAA) (Many things stubbed out, but it gets the general idea across)

Comment: incredible solution! worked like a charm thanks!